# Java class: for getOrder, getData, updateData operation

Tags: java, design-patterns, set

Problem Statement :

Design a class for three operations for given set of integers :

```
int getOrder(int data) /* order meaning rank in list */
int getData(int order)
void updateData(int oldData, int newData) /* [Most used operation] */
```

My solution

```
class App {

    Set<Integer> appData; 

    public App(List<Integer> data) {
        this.appData = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                if(o1 > o2) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1 < o2) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        appData.addAll(data);
    }


    public int getOrder(int m) {
        int counter = 1;
        for(Integer i : this.appData) {
            if(i == m) {
                return counter;
            }
            counter ++ ;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int getdata(int order) {
        int counter = 1;
        for(Integer data : this.appData) {
            if(counter == order) {
                return data;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void updatedata(int olddata, int newdata) {
        if(appData.contains(olddata)) {
            this.appData.remove(olddata);
        }
        this.appData.add(newdata);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the variable `mark` in your code? I don't see it declared anywhere. When copying code to Code Review, please make sure that you copy your code, all your (required) code, exactly your code, and nothing but your code, so help you.... code.

Comment: Are you able to use Java 8 ?

Comment: No.. No java 8. Only Java 6.

Answer (score 2):

(Please post working code next time.)

So first off, there are imports missing, so this doesn't compile as it
is, and the variable `mark` doesn't exist.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Comparator;
```

Either you import by name, or the whole package, just stick with one.

```
...
        if(counter == order) {
            return data;
        }
...
```

Then you should generally specify the visibility on all things,
otherwise you end up with package visibility, which is probably not what
you want.

```
public class App {
...
private Set<Integer> appData;
```

Use of generics is good, the constructor is okay except for the
unnecessary manual comparison.  This should be either using
`TreeSet.descendingSet`, or `Comparator.reverseOrder`, e.g.:

```
public App(List<Integer> data) {
    this.appData = new TreeSet<Integer>(Comparator.<Integer>reverseOrder());
    appData.addAll(data);
}
```

Some whitespace is also off and the spelling of methods should be
consistent, i.e. `getdata` should be get `getData` and `updatedata`
should be `updateData` *as is mentioned in your spec*.

That just to get you started here.

Comment: When posting on Code Review, it is very normal to just skip the imports, especially for `java.util` classes.

Comment: I don't agree because that means I have to do work to get it to compile.

Comment: I think this would be a [good discussion for chat in the 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: Is treeset best thing for these operations ? I don't see any mention of complexity on java doc of that. Was confused between priority queue and treeset..